# Android/Java: how to define a specific class usable in an xml layout file?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

I am not satisfied with the default ImageButton item provided with the Android SDK and I want to define my own ImageButton (lets call it SquareImageButton) which extends from ImageButton.

I consequently create a class like this:

```
public class SquareImageButton extends ImageButton {

// Here I want to include some code which would for example
// force the width of the SquareImageButton to be equal to its height
// And many other things !!!

}
```

Now I want to use this SquareImageButton in xml like I would use a usual ImageButton. For example like this:

```
<SquareImageButton
            android:id="@+id/speakButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_rounded_no_shadow_144px"
           />
```

How should I write in my SquareImageButton class to do this ? Any other things to do to be able to include my SquareImageButton in my xml with no compile or runtime errors ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: You have to add the package name:

Answer (score 2):

> How should I write in my SquareImageButton class to do this ?

I'd override all the constructors offered by `ImageButton`, especially `ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`, as that should be the one used by layout inflation. Make sure the class and these constructors are `public`. That should be all you need.

Note that you will need to fully-qualify the class name as the XML element (`<com.regis.ag.SquareImageButton>`), as your class is not in a well-known package like `android.widget`.

Comment: I made public to constructors and adapter class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try entreing your full package name:

```
<com.your.package.name.SquareImageButton
        android:id="@+id/speakButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_rounded_no_shadow_144px"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the `class` property and you are done.

```
      <Button
        class="com.example.SquareImageButton" 
        android:id="@+id/speakButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_rounded_no_shadow_144px"
       />
```

You can find it using the `findById` method in your `Activity` for example like any buit-in element.

As for the class: you just need to override all abstract methods / constructors in your derived class.